# Can't import shapefile in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, import, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to plot district boundaries on a map of Nepal.  For that I  downloaded a shapefile of districts in Nepal from this site:

> http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d4ad6faa446b42bd9f1d42407db7b5ba

The folder name was  NP_75DWGS84 and all the files within the folder had the files containing the same name. Then I used the following code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


map = Basemap()    
map.drawmapboundary()
map.drawcoastlines()
map.readshapefile('/home/mala/NP_75DWGS84/NP_75DWGS84','NP_75DWGS84',linewidth=1.0,drawbounds = False)
plt.show()
```

It gives me total plot of world, but, it is not plotting shapefiles in the graph. There is also no error. What is wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a directory named "NP_75DWGS84" and a shapefile named "NP_75DWGS84" in that directory?

Comment: @Aaron yes, I have the  directory and the shape file

Comment: Please be more specifiy. Your title is about not being able to "import" a Shapefile but reading the rest suggests you are getting no errors but just  an empty plot? Is that correct? Do your basemap extents and the data coincide?

Comment: @bugmenot123 .I am ploting domain of nepal and the basemap is of that specific domain. The shape file are of the boundary within the country .I think It should coincide but I don't know  how to find out weather it coincides or not.

Comment: Try removing all parameters from the Basemap() initialisation.

Comment: @bugmenot123  I removed parameter but it still doesn't give me shapefile

Comment: Please update your code in the question to reflect that and please be specific! You mean that it still does not render a graphical representation of the shapefile's data, right? No one is handing out files. ;)

Comment: @bugmenot123 I have updated my question. Hope It helps

Comment: I said remove the parameters from the Basemap() initialisation, you still kept some in there.

Comment: @bugmenot123 I have temoved the parameters

Comment: Try "drawbounds = True" or delete this parameter? When drawbounds is false the shapefile is not drawn, returning the geometry instead for you to add to the plot as needed.

Comment: @MarcPfister I tried it but still no shapefile plotted

Comment: Works for me with drawbounds=True. Try removing the mapboundaries and coastlines as well. https://i.imgur.com/ox4zyvv.png

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the extent of the map when you create the Basemap() object, by setting the lower left and upper right corner coordinates, e.g.:

```
map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=80.0,llcrnrlat=26.2,urcrnrlon=88.3,urcrnrlat=30.6)
map.drawmapboundary()
map.readshapefile('/home/mala/NP_75DWGS84/NP_75DWGS84','NP_75DWGS84',linewidth=1.0,drawbounds = False)
plt.show()
```